# Running VBS script from VBA - Unrecognized DB Format

Tags: vba, vbscript, adodb, ms-access-2016

I'm creating vbs script that will work as auto updater for tool which uses MS Access as front end. VBS script will be launched with VBA code from MS Access (1). Part of this script is function that detects current version of the tool by creating ADODB connection to tool front end file (Test.accdb) and reading "CurrentVersion" value from "tblLocalParameters" table (2).

The problem is that when I double click on script the function with ADODB works correctly but when I try to run it with MS Access VBA it throws out error:
"Unrecognized database format"

I'm not sure if more information about whole auto updater script is necessary but my plan was to: Check with SQL db if tool is up to date. If not - launch updater script. Script will close MS Access with shell command then copy new file and run MS Access again.

I tried to run same script from excel and from other MS Access file, it caused same error.

I'll be gratefull for help with getting rid of "Unrecognized database format" error.

```
MS ACCESS CODE:
(1) 
Dim Test()
    Shell "wscript ""C:\Test_Folder\TEST.vbs""", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

```
(2)
VBS SCRIPT CODE
Option Explicit

Dim strFile

strFile = "C:\Test_Folder\TEST.accdb"

WScript.Echo  FileReadAccessDB(strFile,"tblLocalParameters","ParameterValue","ParameterName","'VersionCurrent'")

'-------------------------------------------------------------
Function FileReadAccessDB(DbPath, tblName,fldName,IdCol,IdVal)
    Dim cn, rs
    Dim qSQL
    Dim errNo

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection") 

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DbPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    cn.Open

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    qSQL = "SELECT " & fldName & " FROM " & tblName & " WHERE " & IdCol &  " = " & IdVal
    rs.open qSQL, cn

    FileReadAccessDB =  rs.fields(fldName).value

    rs.close
    cn.close

End Function
```

Comment: Start by using a more recent provider (I think Access 2016 comes with `ACE.OLEDB.16.0`). Using a database in shared mode often is difficult. However, I recommend storing such parameters in the database properties table, that way you can properly store the right type without having a separate table for every type.

Comment: Can you explain why can't you just run the VBS code in your VBA code? Also, can you explain where (which line) in the VBS the error occurs?

Comment: Problematic line: cn.Open. Why not run the VBS code in your VBA code: Each user have his own MS Access tool file under documents folder and shortcut to it on the desktop.I want to have control over version that people are using. From my experience asking kindly users to delete old version of tool and copy new one is bad idea. If update is necessary user will get pop up and button with label 'Update now'. This is where I need a VBS script - idea was to run this script from MS Access, script will close it, replace files and open again. I can't replace file that is in use.

Comment: I just don't understand why the VBS script works fine when I run it with double click but not when I open it with shell command in Excel/Access vba editor.

Comment: You're trying to access a database file from inside that database file, what is there to understand? That's why just the VBScript works because you haven't already got the database open in MSAccess.

Comment: That is not the case. VB Script uses ObjShell.AppActivate(ProcessName) then objShell.SendKeys "% C" to close access database file. File is closed when script creates ADODB connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found source of the issue. I decided to abandon VBS and create C# console app. During testing I found that connection string (provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0") works only when I set platform target to x64.

My Windows is 64bit but Office is 32bit. Double click in explorer launched the scrip as x64 but MS Access vba shell launched it as x86.

I found some code, added it to the script - it solved the problem.

```
If InStr(LCase(WScript.FullName),"syswow64") Then
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """%systemroot%\sysnative\wscript.exe"" """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """"
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

If the script runs in 32 bit mode on 64 bit windows, it re-runs itself in 64 bit mode.

[Credit](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/e9f2a135-6675-4a2d-95cf-9d880b0a9cab/how-to-get-vbscript-running-in-64-bit-mode?forum=ITCG)